# Getting raw data from a Blogger "page"

Tags: android, blogger

Is there an easy way to extract the raw data from a Blogger "page". For example, please see the following page:

http://ftaca.blogspot.com/p/get-support.html

I'd like to scrape everything from "Get Support" through "p 82 ACA text" (essentially, the meat of the page without the surrounding navs and such) for use in an Android app that is related to this website. Are there any querystrings that I can append to the URL to just get the raw info (i.e. something like http://ftaca.blogspot.com/p/get-support.html?raw=1)? I've tried a few things, but none work. Mind that this is a Blogger "page", and not a post per se.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is what I need:

http://ftaca.blogspot.com/feeds/pages/default?alt=rss

Thanks everyone for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask the web site developers whether they support query strings for page subsetting. That isn't really Android specific.

If they don't, you'll probably have to write a HttpClient client (search here and you'll find lots of good examples) to get the raw HTML for the page, and then subset it within your Android app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Torid. I know the site developer personally. So, is there a setting in Blogger that allows for query strings to be used in such a manner? (I'm admittedly not the world's Blogger expert...) Thanks, Chris

Comment: I'm not so familiar with Blogger either - but check out http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/reference.html and http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html#Queries. You might be able to get what you want using the fields parameter.